# Purpose of sendto address for C raw socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip, raw-sockets

I'm sending some ping packets via a raw socket in C, on my linux machine.

```
int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

This means that I specify the IP packet header when I write to the socket (`IP_HDRINCL` is implied).

Writing to the socket with `send` fails, telling me I need to specify an address.

If I use `sendto` then it works.  For `sendto` I must specify a `sockaddr_in` struct to use, which includes the fields `sin_family`, `sin_port` and `sin_addr`.

However, I have noticed a few things:

- The `sin_family` is `AF_INET` - which was already specified when the socket was created.
- The `sin_port` is naturally unused (ports are not a concept for IP).
- It doesn't matter what address I use, so long as it is an external address (the IP packet specifies 8.8.8.8 and the `sin_addr` specifies 1.1.1.1).

It seems none of the extra fields in `sendto` are actually used to great extent.  So, is there a technical reason why I have to use `sendto` instead of `send` or is it just an oversight in the API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Writing to the socket with `send` fails, telling me I need to specify an address.

It fails, because the `send()` function can only be used on *connected* sockets (as stated [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send)). Usually you would use `send()` for TCP communication (connection-oriented) and `sendto()` can be used to send UDP datagrams (connectionless).

Since you want to send "ping" packets, or more correctly ICMP datagrams, which are clearly connectionless, you have to use the `sendto()` function.

> It seems none of the extra fields in `sendto` are actually used to great
>   extent. So, is there a technical reason why I have to use `sendto`
>   instead of `send` or is it just an oversight in the API?

**Short answer:**

When you are not allowed to use `send()`, then there is only one option left, called `sendto()`.

**Long answer:**

It is not just an oversight in the API. If you want to send a UDP datagram by using an ordinary socket (e.g. `SOCK_DGRAM`), `sendto()` needs the information about the destination address and port, which you provided in the struct `sockaddr_in`, right? The kernel will insert that information into the resulting IP header, since the struct `sockaddr_in` is the *only* place where you specified who the receiver will be. Or in other words: in this case the kernel has to take the destination info from your struct as you don't provide an additional IP header.

Because `sendto()` is not only used for UDP but also raw sockets, it has to be a more or less "generic" function which can cover all the different use cases, even when some parameters like the port number are not relevant/used in the end.

For instance, by using `IPPROTO_RAW` (which automatically implies `IP_HDRINCL`), you show your intention that you want to create the IP header on your own. Thus the last two arguments of `sendto()` are actually redundant information, because they're already included in the data buffer you pass to `sendto()` as the second argument. Note that, even when you use `IP_HDRINCL` with your raw socket, the kernel will fill in the source address and checksum of your IP datagram if you set the corresponding fields to `0`.

If you want to write your own ping program, you could also change the last argument in your `socket()` function from `IPPROTO_RAW` to `IPPROTO_ICMP` and let the kernel create the IP header for you, so you have one thing less to worry about. Now you can easily see how the two `sendto()`-parameters `*dest_addr` and `addrlen` become significant again because it's the only place where you provide a destination address.

The language and APIs are very old and have grown over time. Some APIs can look weird from todays perspective but you can't change the old interfaces without breaking a huge amount of existing code. Sometimes you just have to get used to things that were defined/designed many years or decades ago.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to InvertedHeli's answer, the `dest_addr` passed in `sendto()` will be used by kernel to determine which network interface to used.

For example, if `dest_addr` has ip `127.0.0.1` and the raw packet has dest address `8.8.8.8`, your packet will still be routed to the `lo` interface.

Answer (score 2):

The `send()` call is used when the sockets are in a TCP `SOCK_STREAM` connected state.

From the man page:

> the send() call may be used only when the socket is in a connected
>       state (so  that  the intended recipient is known).

Since your application obviously does not connect with any other socket, we cannot expect `send()` to work.